# Scroll to Bottom of <object>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is there a way to scroll to the bottom of an html `<object>`? I usually use the following for elements but this doesnt seem to work on `<object>`

```
$(document).ready( function (){
    let elm = $('object');
    elm.scrollTop(elm.prop("scrollHeight"));    
});
```

Comment: And it work [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/StepBaro/dcgt03pL/)

Comment: @Baro it works because you are using it on a `<div>` with the `id` set to `"object"` this however does not demonstrate that it works on an `<object>`